# Payload JWT structure

Tags: java, jwt

I am trying to set up my JWT token but it has a different payload structure as usual,
How can i set this kind of payload structure?

```
{
  "https://daml.com/ledger-api": {
    "ledgerId": "sandbox",
    "applicationId": "foobar",
    "actAs": ["Alice"]    
  }
}
```

i can only set up something like this:

```
{           
 "sub": "https://daml.com/ledger-api",
 "ledgerId": "sandbox",
 "applicationId": "foobar",
 "actAs": "[Alice]"
}
```

My java code:

```
void getJWT() throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
                 
    Claims claims = Jwts.claims().setSubject("https://daml.com/ledger-api");
    claims.put("ledgerId","sandbox");
    claims.put("applicationId", "foobar");
    claims.put("actAs", "[Alice]");
    String jwtToken = Jwts.builder()
            .setClaims(claims)
            .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS256, "sYn2kjibddFAWtnPJ2AFlL8WXmohJMCvigQggaEypa5E=".getBytes("UTF-8"))
            .setHeaderParam("typ", Header.JWT_TYPE)
            .compact();
    System.out.println("The generated jwt token is as follows:" + jwtToken);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can i set this kind of payload structure?
>
> ```
> {
>   "https://daml.com/ledger-api": {
>     "ledgerId": "sandbox",
>     "applicationId": "foobar",
>     "actAs": ["Alice"]    
>   }
> }
> ```

You can easily achive the above payload structure by modifying your code as describe below.

```
void getJWT() throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    Map<String, String> claims = new HashMap<String, String>();
    claims.put("ledgerId", "sandbox");
    claims.put("applicationId", "foobar");
    claims.put("actAs", "[Alice]");

    Map<String, Object> claimsMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    claimsMap.put("https://daml.com/ledger-api", claims);

    String jwtToken = Jwts.builder()
            .setClaims(claimsMap)
            .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS256, "sYn2kjibddFAWtnPJ2AFlL8WXmohJMCvigQggaEypa5E=".getBytes("UTF-8"))
            .setHeaderParam("typ", Header.JWT_TYPE)
            .compact();

    System.out.println("The generated jwt token is as follows:" + jwtToken);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! Do you know how can i get the [ ] before the "" ? Like ["Alice"] instead of "[Alice]"?